# Are foreign key constraints checked when child table row is updated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

Using the example from PostgresSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), where `orders.product_no` references foreign key `products.product_no`. Consider the following updates on the "child table" `orders`:

1. `UPDATE orders SET product_no = 'new_no', quantity = 'new_quantity'`
2. `UPDATE orders SET quantity = 'new_quantity'`

Does the `product_no` foreign key constraint happen for these two commands? Intuitively, I'd guess the answer is Yes for `1` and No for `2`. However, I couldn't find documentation that explicitly mentions this.

The motivation for this question is that we have a large table with some foreign key constraints, and the rows are frequently updated (which doesn't touch the columns with constraints). We were wondering if dropping the foreign key constraints would help speed up the updates.

Comment: If you don't need to update the FK (`product_no = 'new_no'`) don't include it in the UPDATE. That way the constraint won't be checked.

Answer (score 2):

Never, never, drop a foreign key for a measly few ms shorter run time. FKs are how you maintain data integrity which is vastly more important then a reduced runtime. And in this case it will **not make a difference** any way.